# Help installing libboost-system-dev, et al

Tags: apt

I am trying to install GPU-Ocelot, a GPU emulator, on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.  I am stuck at the following line of the installation instruction manual:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-thread-dev
```

I have managed to install the first of those (libboost-dev, as version 1.48.0.2; the instructions suggest a version 1.46 or greater) but the rest refuse to install.  The precise error is (in this case, for libboost-all-dev):

```
E: Package 'libboost-all-dev' has no installation candidate
```

running "apt-cache policy" for those packages reveals no install and no candidate.  Running "apt-get update" does not help.

I am new to Ubuntu (getting the GPU-Ocelot to work was my main goal in installing it in the first place) but I gather I need to modify the /etc/apt/sources.list file, either manually or through the software center GUI.  But I don't know what information to put in there or how I would go about finding the information.

(There are more apt-get steps following the one I'm stuck on, which may or may not give me the same problem when I get to them.  I would greatly appreciate knowing what to put into the sources.list file, but I would also appreciate knowing how you know that.)

Comment: libboost-all-dev was not in the command you gave. So you did `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`?

Comment: On your suggestion, yes.  Same result.

Answer (score 1):

These packages are in the 'Universe'. These are packages are not regulated by Ubuntu but are delivered from the community and are in status 'Superseded' and are all optional.

To be able to install from the universe, the easiest way is to enable them in the Software Sources.

To enable these from the command line use: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"`

Next, run `sudo apt-get update` to update the database with the added repository.

Comment: No dice-- Universe was already installed according to the Software Sources GUI.  To be safe, I entered the command you gave.  The command executed with no errors, but I get the same results when trying to install.

Comment: Which archive are you using? The package is certainly in this one: Version table:
     1.48.0.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libboost-all-dev

Comment: After adding it as mentioned by labsin > sudo apt-get update

Comment: And try to change the server as ubfan mentioned. Some have not all packages. Just change it to 'main' to be safe. (It's in the same GUI I think). Then again do a sudo apt-get update.
You can always download it from the link above. (i386 -> 32bit and amd64 -> 64bit)